# Designing an EMP Generator for school :^)

Tags: power, circuit-design, inductor, electromagnetism, pulse

How would I go about calculating and designing a circuit that can produce an axial magnetic field greater than 20 Tesla for about 1.4 μs (full width at half maximum). The dimensions of the solenoid must meet the constraint of a cylinder with length=5mm and radius=0.5mm.  The risetime of the pulse must be less than or equal to 1μs.

This lab seems like a LOT to digest... Anyways, I figured it would make most sense to use a capacitive energy storage device. How would I go about beginning to develop a design for this, assuming that this needs to be buildable with real life components, and not just have a 2000A current source powering a solenoid with a little switch :^) Any pointers on what formulas to start looking at, terms to start googling would help. I tried to solve this as a physics problem, but I'm not getting much information from that. I assume this requires a more intricate usage of 1st and 2nd Order circuits.

Thanks in advance for the help! :P

Comment: You've specified the radius of the cylinder. Over what area within that radius must the 20 T be produced? How will the measurement be made?

Comment: Marx generator? Supercooled magnet?

Comment: I'm thinking that the area which the 20T field must act upon is within the inner diameter of the solenoid. Not outside the solenoid. @jonk

Comment: You can easily calculate the magnetic field of a solenoid. The problem is 20 Tesla is a lot. For this not to be trivial you must be expected to take heating into consideration. But thats a whole problem itself, especially given how small the thing is supposed to be. You will probably want superconductors, but thats not something many labs are going to get into.

Comment: What makes you think it is possible.? Do the math.  Compute the concentric force vs current

Comment: How many Henry/Tesla,  Ohm-Amps, Tesla/m,  N/m, MW/T , H/Ohm=Tau1  etc ?  Then to energize, How many kV, mF, mF-mOhm=Tau2 , Q, A-s and how explosive is the coil and capacitor.?

Comment: @ChrisChoo Of course we aren't talking about outside. I think that goes completely without saying. I was curious about the measurement device used and how much of the central core area it senses and averages. 500 microns is the diameter of the entire coil. Over how many microns of that diameter will you be measuring the field? But I recommend reading "Seungyong Hahn et al. 45.5-tesla direct-current magnetic field generated with a high-temperature superconducting magnet, Nature (2019.)" Their coil was pretty small, though not as small as you suggest. Small is good, though.

Comment: Make  a lightning rod and make 5000A CT to measure it.  Do it remotely.  That should give you 1 us rise time and a 10us tail.

Comment: You might want to consider explosive flux compression, 45T is a lot, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Explosively_pumped_flux_compression_generator

Comment: Why so small a coil? (Fine if it's what you need and you can deliver the current, but, can you?

Comment: @ChrisChoo Perform some of the calculations necessary to show, purely by theory alone, how you might approach this problem. The authors of the article I mentioned performed theoretical calculations ***before*** they built and tested their device. That set of calculations involved a *lot more* than simple electronics models commonly applied here. They achieved a result that was within 0.2 T of their prediction, which is a testament to their many years of prior experience and current state of comprehensive, theoretical knowledge. Can you even so much as scratch the surface of that work?

Comment: @ChrisChoo If I were you, I'd immediately write to the author(s) and ask them about your question. They are in a very, very good position to help you and could provide you with a "yes/no" answer, likely the primary reason or two why, if no, etc. It also might put you in touch with some good folks who are really excited to see that there are lay people actually curious about their work.

Answer (score 0):

over 0.5 millimeter, you can only wrap the tiniest of wire gauge.

Give copper of size a METER has thermal time constant 9600 seconds,
of size 0.1 meter is 96 seconds,
of size 0.01 meter is 0.96 seconds
of size 0.001 meter (1 millimeter( is 0.0096 seconds (9.6 milliseconds)
of size 0.0001 meter (100 microns, or 4X that of bondwires used in silicon packages)
is 0.000096 seconds or 9.6 microseconds,

then the thermal duration 9.6uS >> 1uS suggests you **CAN** build something that thermally **MIGHT** survive long enough.

You can now examine the mechanical stresses (sudden acceleration) of gold wires (why not) only 25 micron in diameter.

And examine the rate of heat generation, to determine if the many? turns of gold wire will vaporize, or that the surface merely will ablate away because SKIN EFFECT will keep the heat on the surface.

Have fun.